# Creating Survey Questions/Answers for Admin Sections

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an application for my company in which i am stuck at thinking what would be the best approach for doing this.

The company already have a page for survey around 15 questions with multiple choices. Now i have been asked to develop an application so that from admin section they can modify the existing questions and their options, also they can add more questions and options.

I am not sure what would be the best approach for doing this. I was thinking creating a page in admin section where they can see existing questions and answer options, if they modify it i can directly change it in the database and if they add more questions, I can go and create a custom questions fields in the database. For answers option i will not create any fields in the database as i will generate options dynamically like textboxes, checkboxes, radiobuttons etc.. and when user select the answer i will put pnly selected answers in the database.

## EDIT

=======

## I just want to give admin only 3 options for adding options ( checkbox, radios, textbox )

I am confused as how to create controls dynamically using generics. like admin can pass in the values in the method like this CreateControls(TextBox, NoOfOptions, List)

Please forgive me for not adding any code in my questions as i have not yet started working on this and stuck at the first stage of thinking process.

I am using VS2010, .Net 4.0, SQL server 208 R2 for this application.

Please advice. any working example Link would be appreciated.

Comment: main problem is how admin select control which you want to show and to generate controls here?Am i right ?

Comment: yes. admin can select which control goes with the question. it could be checkbox, textbox, radiobutton. and i need to create no of control depending on the selection and give them the values.

Answer (score 1):

I have one idea regarding this.I already done this kind of functionality but in my case each custom question is bind with textbox only.

In you case we can follow these steps :

**Admin End :**

Specify each control with unique value it may be number or control name.Save this in table with question id.

**Client End :**

1.) Take repeater.In item template take following controls :

a.)Label (Your custom question)

b.)textboxes (visible false)

c.)checkboxes (visible false)

d.)radiobuttons (visible false) etc.

2.)Bind this repeater with questions table.

3.)Now fire rowdatabound event and set visibility of controls on the basis of question id.

May this help you if you have any doubt please ask .

**UPDATE :**

Now please check the implementation of whole process which i had discussed yesterday :

**XML file use as test database :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

 <catalog>
  <cd>
  <id>1</id>
  <title>Question 1</title>
  <ctrl>1</ctrl>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <id>2</id>
  <title>Question change</title>
  <ctrl>2</ctrl>
 </cd>
  <cd>
   <id>3</id>
   <title>Question 3</title>
  <ctrl>3</ctrl>
  </cd>
 <cd>
   <id>4</id>
   <title>Question 4</title>
  <ctrl>2</ctrl>
 </cd>
```

**ASPX page :**

```
       <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ctrl") %>' />
                </td>
                 <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="YES" TextAlign="Left" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="NO" TextAlign="Left" Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

**CS file :**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        HiddenField ctrl = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1");
        if (ctrl.Value == "1")//1 for Textbox
        {
            TextBox txtCtrl = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1");
            txtCtrl.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (ctrl.Value == "3")//3 for Radio Button
        {
            RadioButton rdbYCtrl = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("RadioButton1");
            RadioButton rdbNCtrl = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("RadioButton2");
            rdbYCtrl.Visible = true;
            rdbNCtrl.Visible = true;
        }
        else if(ctrl.Value == "2")//2 for Chackbox
        {
             CheckBox chkCtrl = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
             chkCtrl.Visible = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this help you now :-)

Comment: I am gonna try this tonight.. will let you know how it goes

Comment: ok,i am waiting for your reply.If you still face any problem then please let me know.

Comment: is this possible using generic method?.. like i dont have to specify the TYPE that i want to create. i.e one method that creates Checkbox,Textbox,Radios

Comment: How many controls you have in your list?Only these three or some more?Please update your question with your latest code so that i can check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28093/discussion-between-sunny-and-patel-milanb)

Comment: I am still working on this sunny... thanks for your help.. i am getting  there slowly...

Answer (score 1):

Prettiest way to do this is to write a webcontrol. PLace it inside the ItemTemplate of teh Repeater. The repeater will do the databinding job, where as the webcontrol will render the question and the answer fields for each questions.

What I can imagine at the momment is, your datasource (that is bound to ther repeater must have at least:

1. QuestionID - This is to identify the question
2. Question - this contains the question
3. ResponseType - this is just a flag to determine whether to render textbox, radio or checkbox as the answer field/s

The webcontrol must have at least these properties:

1. QuestionID
2. Question
3. ResponseType
4. UserAnswer
5. Choices - collection of choice

During itemdatabound event of the repeater, get the webcontrol instance in the itemtemplate. assign the questionid and question from the bound DataItem to the respective webcontrol properties. Then check the AnswerType. if it's either radio or checkbox, retrieve the choices from the db/xml for this particular questionid, and assign it to the webcontrol Choices property.

Now at the webcontrol's `RenderContents` event:

1. write the question
2. if AnswerType is textbox, write textarea or textbox element
3. if AnswerType is either radio or checkbox, iterate the Choices property to render the respective input tags.

Anyway, if you use this approach, the admin can set unlimited number of choices for each questions. Each question can have flexibility. Image can be attached to questions, even as the choices like those IQ test.

However, there are a lot more to code in the webcontrol like, maintaining data on postbacks, fieldvalidation, etc.